# `xinput` command not being applied from ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

Tags: raspbian, lxde

My `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` file has the following contents:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate inverted
@xinput set-prop "HID 27c0:0818" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1
@xset s blank
@chromium-browser https://calendar.google.com/
```

All of these steps are taking place, except the `@xinput set-prop ...` command.

The touch panel touch interface is not being rotated (inverted) as per that command. The screen output is being inverted correctly (the `@xrandr --output ...` command is working), and chrome opens automatically, but the touch is not inverted as it should be

If I go over the the pi and execute the `@xinput` command as it is written above, it will fix my issue, but I want this to run when the pi reboots and the user logs into the desktop, automatically.

What did I do wrong ?

(the same issue was happening when this file was located at `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`